# Update column values based on the data in the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
[Associate ID] [Reporting Date] [Time Quantity]
103554         2020-08-31           8
103554         2020-09-01           8
103554         2020-09-02           8
```

Table 2

```
[Associate ID] [1] [2] [3]-------[31] [Month] [Year] 
103554                                  8      2020
103554                                  9      2020
```

I want a SQL query to update Table 2 based on the [Reporting Date] column. [1] to [31] are the days of the month in Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

Horrible data model.  But, you can do this using aggregation and then `join`ing in the results:

```
update table2
    set col_01 = t1.t1_01,
        col_02 = t1.t1_02,
        . . .
    from (select associate_id, year(reporting_date) as yyyy, month(reporting_date) as mm,
                 sum(case when day(reporting_date) = 1 then time_quantity end) as tq_01,
                 sum(case when day(reporting_date) = 2 then time_quantity end) as tq_02,
                 . . .
          from table1
          group by associate_id, year(reporting_date) as yyyy, month(reporting_date)
         ) t1
         on t1.associate_id = table2.associate_id and
            t1.yyyy = table2.year and
            t1.mm = table2.month;
```

Comment: Any suggestions to improve the data model?

Comment: @Lilly . . . Just write a query to fetch the data on-the-fly or format it at the application level.

Comment: @Lilly: The data model Gordon is talking of: Drop Table 2. Table 1 contains the data already. Don't store it redundantly.